# How to initialize empty data frame and add columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
dummify = function (listOfSmbin, df) {
    dummified = list(NULL)
    #for all columns
for (col in colnames) {
    #generate dummified column
    dummified[col] = smbinning.gen(df[col], listOfSmbin[col], col)
    }
return(dummified)
}
```

I want to add n * 1 shaped dataframes one by one.

In order to do so, I need to first initialize an empty data frame before going into the for loop.

However, when I initialize an empty data frame, I can't add columns with 1 or more rows since the initialized data frame has 0 rows.

(It didn't work the same even if I initialize a data frame with column names)

Comment: What is the end point you're trying to achieve? A number of dataframes with n rows and 1 column? `rbind()`might help if that's the case. Also, R is a vectorised language so these `for` loops can almost certainly be made more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous what type of object `smbinning.gen` takes as input, if the first two can be vectors, then the following code should work; if it takes data.frames as input, then use `smbinning.gen(as.data.frame(var1), as.data.frame(var2), colName)`.

```
dummified <- Map(function(var1, var2, colName){ 
        smbinning.gen(var1, var2, colName)
    }, df, listOfSmbin, colnames)
dummified <- as.data.frame(dummified)
```